# Convert PDF from sRGB color space to CMYK

Tags: colors, pdf, ps

Does anyone know how I can convert a PDF (or EPS) file from sRGB color space to CMYK color space?

My workflow is currently the following:

- Draw an image with Powerpoint
- Print via postscript printer into a .prn postscript file
- Execute a bash script that uses ps2eps, ps2pdf, and pdftk in order to generate a cropped PDF image

Unfortunately, this produces an sRGB PDF only. Instead, I need a CMYK PDF and I don't have an idea how I may get this.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You are already using Ghostscript in ps2pdf, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418268/script-or-some-other-means-to-convert-rgb-to-cmyk-in-pdf) would do it:

```
gswin32c.exe 
-o c:/path/to/output-cmyk.pdf 
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite 
-dUseCIEColor 
-sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK 
-sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK 
-sColorConversionStrategyForImages=CMYK 
 input-rgb.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, unfortunately if I execute this command I only get this error message: `Unable to convert color space to CMYK, reverting strategy to LeaveColorUnchanged.`

Comment: You can try to remove -dUseCIEColor . This is explained here as an apparent bug: http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693169

Answer (score 0):

well, you are naming a lot of stuff here, the point is: you want a conversion from an already existing file or you want to know how write a postscript file that goes with a CMYK color space ?

In general terms the postscript is used with an RGB color space, and a CMYK color space is just a conversion from RGB to CMYK, so in short, RGB is the "default" color space for PS.

In postscript you can explicitly call a CMYK conversion with `/DeviceCMYK` and you can read more about this in any Postscript related doc, for example [this pdf](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/sdk/TN5604.DeviceN_Color.pdf).

there is also a sample with this tag [here](http://users.wfu.edu/chindw/Work/CodePortfolio/Postscript/binary_coord.html).

But unless you really know what you are doing, I suggest to live it as it is, your document will be less complicated and if you are using a monitor, you are using an RGB color space, so in the end nothing changes that much for you unless you have really special requirements.